# Converting to Delphi 64 bit?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

OgUtil.pas in onguard I want to porting to  64 bit
 Delphi 64 bit not allow to use ASM with pascal Can I convert this function to work with delphi 64 bit

```
function LockFile(Handle : THandle;
              FileOffsetLow, FileOffsetHigh,
              LockCountLow, LockCountHigh : Word) : Boolean;
    var
   Error : Word;
begin
asm
mov   ax,$5C00
    mov   bx,Handle
mov   cx,FileOffsetHigh
mov   dx,FileOffsetLow
mov   si,LockCountHigh
mov   di,LockCountLow
int   $21
jc    @@001
xor   ax,ax
@@001:
mov   Error,ax
end;
Result := Error = 0;
end;
```

can convert this code to completely pascal

```
function UnlockFile(Handle : THandle;
                FileOffsetLow, FileOffsetHigh,
                UnLockCountLow, UnLockCountHigh : Word) : Boolean;
var
Error : Word;
begin
asm
mov   ax, $5C01
mov   bx,Handle
mov   cx,FileOffsetHigh
mov   dx,FileOffsetLow
mov   si,UnLockCountHigh
mov   di,UnLockCountLow
int   $21
jc    @@001
xor   ax, ax
@@001:
mov   Error, ax
end;
Result := Error = 0;
end;
```

Delphi 64 bit not allow to use ASM with pascal Can I convert this function to work with delphi 64 bit
Please help to converting this code to pascal

Comment: Given the 16-bit file handle and offsets, I have my doubts whether this code even works in 32-bit Windows. Question whether *converting* this code is really the best action; *deleting* it might be more appropriate. The OS already provides file-locking API functions anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Delphi x64 compiler does indeed support inline assembler. There is nothing to stop you writing inline assembler for the x64 compiler.

However, this is 16 bit code, and you cannot port it to either the 32 bit or 64 bit compiler. I suspect that what you have here is that OnGuard supports both 16 bit and 32 bit code. And it uses conditional compilation in places where there needs to be different implementation for 16 and 32 bit code. I bet that the OnGuard assumes that anything that is not 32 bit code is 16 bit code.

So there will likely be a `{$IFDEF WIN32}` test somewhere. And the code will not define `LockFile` and `UnlockFile` if that condition evaluates to `True` because the functions are defined in the Windows API now. And when that condition evaluates to `False`, the code assumes 16 bit and defines the functions. But since you are trying to support x64, the `{$IFDEF WIN32}` check evaluates `False` and the code attempts to compile 16 bit code, obviously doomed to fail.

Frankly, the best thing you can do is to remove all of the 16 bit code from this library. That will help you see the wood from the trees. I expect there will be other places in the code which attempt to use the 16 bit code simply because `Win32` is not defined in the 64 bit compiler.

**Update**

And a quick check of the OnGuard repo reveals this code, just as I suspected:

```
{$IFNDEF Win32}
function LockFile(Handle : THandle; FileOffsetLow, FileOffsetHigh,
                  LockCountLow, LockCountHigh : Word) : Boolean;
function UnlockFile(Handle : THandle; FileOffsetLow, FileOffsetHigh,
                    UnLockCountLow, UnLockCountHigh : Word) : Boolean;
function FlushFileBuffers(Handle : THandle) : Boolean;
{$ENDIF}
```

And there are plenty more tests of `Win32` which assume that the lack of that define means that the code is 16 bit. Truly this is 20<sup>th</sup> century code!

You need to look through the library for all uses of the `Win32` conditional. Each and every one that you find will present a porting problem for x64.

The basic strategy you must adopt is that you want to use the `Win32` variant for both 32 bit and 64 bit. So if I were you I would simply hunt down every `Win32` conditional and remove the conditional. Leave behind the `Win32` branch of the conditional.

Answer (score 8):

You are calling the old DOS `LockFile` and `UnlockFile` functions via the interruption **21h**, you can update and replace these calls by the [LockFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and  [UnlockFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  WinApi methods, which are defined in the Windows unit.

```
function LockFile(hFile: THandle; dwFileOffsetLow, dwFileOffsetHigh: DWORD;
  nNumberOfBytesToLockLow, nNumberOfBytesToLockHigh: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;

function UnlockFile(hFile: THandle; dwFileOffsetLow, dwFileOffsetHigh: DWORD;
  nNumberOfBytesToUnlockLow, nNumberOfBytesToUnlockHigh: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
```